# Coerce Specific Ethernet Connector On Managed MAC-based VLAN

Tags: vlan

I'm mostly asking here because I do not know how to find an existing answer for this if one exists anywhere.

I have a Netgear Prosafe GS748T managed switch. I am working on an industrial application that uses the CC-Link IE protocol, which only uses MAC addresses and not IP adresses.

I need assign MAC addresses of devices on the network to specific ethernet ports on the switch. The devices on this network must be unable to communicate if they are not connected to their assigned/configured physical ethernet connector.

Does that make sense? I feel like this might be easy but I might be lacking some critical knowledge of managed switches.

Comment: I don't believe this switch model has that capability, it is on the very low end of the "managed switches" range. The feature you want is called "Port security", at least by Cisco and HP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most switches refer to this as "port security". I'm not certain if the Netgear support it. There are typically a few different ways to configure, the most secure of which is to specify which MAC address is able to communicate through each individual switch port.

Comment: Thank you EEAA! I'm sorry that I don't know anything, I'm just kinda thrown into this today.

Comment: This switch supports MAC-Based Port Authentication, so I think that's exactly what I'm looking for!